# Blank screen on startup when Ubuntu is default boot in BIOS?

Tags: dual-boot

*Very new to Ubuntu and dual booting, sorry for any lack of knowledge in advance.*

I recently created a dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu. I created a partition and used a USB with rufus to download and dual boot Ubuntu. I set everything up and both OS are working perfectly.

**The problem:**

When I went into the BIOS to change the default boot order, making Ubuntu the default, I sometimes get a completely blank screen on system startup. I can manually shut down my computer and restart it and usually the boot loader will then show up. I've switched the default order back to windows to avoid screwing anything up, and currently boot into ubuntu using advanced restart and selecting ubuntu, which works just fine as far as I can tell.

**Questions:**

Since this method of booting into Windows, advanced restart, selecting Ubuntu.. works fine for getting into Ubuntu. Is there anything wrong with this method?

Or even better.. does anyone know why I'm getting a completely blank screen sometimes on startup with Ubuntu as the default boot on BIOS?